# Get time for reaching out a place from current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mapkit

Is it possible to get the reaching time to a particular place from current location latitude longitude to a particular place's latitude longitude in a bicycle?

Or may be i should use API to do the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API for finding time from your current location to destination location. (don't know about bicycle transport type)

Below API returns you the possible route to reach at your destination location with distance & how much time your need to reach to the destination place.

[Google API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.033863,72.585022&destination=23.055,72.565022&sensor=false)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Please add the appropriate URL for the above api and the which parameters need to be passed in?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-37.797428,145.014135&destination=-37.803500,145.011169&sensor=false&mode=bicycling

Travel Mode = driving, walking, bicycling, transit

If you want to find distance by travel mode Bicycle than you just have to add mode="Your Preferred Mode" like above Link